# ActiveRecord scope using class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have a model to keep 2 users "user" and "worker".

```
create_table "action_logs", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "worker_id"
  t.string   "text_log"
end

class ActionLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :worker, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Now, I want to write a scope using "user" and "worker" on this model.

```
scope :not_inhouse, -> { 
  includes(:user).where( "users.inhouse = ?", false).
  includes(:worker).where( "workers.inhouse = ?", false) 
}
```

But it doesn't work.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: 
  SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: workers.inhouse: 
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "action_logs"."id") FROM "action_logs" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "action_logs"."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" "workers_action_logs" ON "workers_action_logs"."id" = "action_logs"."worker_id" WHERE (users.inhouse = 'f') AND (workers.inhouse = 'f')
```

It seems ActiveRecord doesn't handle class_name as I expected. 
Is there any way to write a scope using class_name?

Comment: You are using `includes` instead of `joins`.

Comment: You could try to do `where( "workers_action_logs.inhouse = ?", false)`, however this is pretty ugly. Got to think for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments. Now I understood 2 points.

- Diffrence between includes and joins.
- ActiveRecords name joined table name, independently of class_name.

So I can write the scope like this:

```
scope :not_inhouse, -> { 
  joins(:user).where( "users.inhouse = ?", false).
  joins(:worker).where( "workers_action_logs.inhouse = ?", false)
}
```

or

```
scope :not_inhouse, -> { 
  joins(:user).where( "users.inhouse = ?", false).
  joins('INNER JOIN "users" "workers" ON workers.id = action_logs.worker_id').
  where( "workers.inhouse = ?", false)
}
```